# Proper use of __format__

Tags: python, string, class, format, python-datamodel

I have a class that defines `__str__` to return the integer value in hex and a `__format__` to return the value formatted with the user's format spec:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, value: int):
        self._value = value

    def __str__(self):
        return '{:04X}'.format(self._value)

    def __format__(self, format_spec):
        return format_spec.format(self._value)
```

So I would expect:

```
'{:04X}'.format(MyClass(10)) == '000A'
```

and

```
 str(MyClass(10)) == '000A'
```

but the `str.format` call just returns the format spec, `04X`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only the spec (the part in the curly braces **after the colon**) is passed to the `__format__` method, in your case that's `'04X'`. That contains no placeholders so calling `format` on it will simply return the `'04X'` again.

In case you want to "pass on" the `format_spec` to `self._value` then you need to do that explicitly, for example using the built-in [`format`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#format) function:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, value: int):
        self._value = value

    def __str__(self):
        return '{:04X}'.format(self._value)

    def __format__(self, format_spec):
        return format(self._value, format_spec)
```

```
>>> '{:04X}'.format(MyClass(10))
'000A'
```